# What is Windows 10 Lean Edition?

Tags: windows-10

I'm reading a lot about Windows 10 Lean Edition, anyone out there will full information about this edition of Windows 10 would like to explain about this edition in layman's language?

Really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From [WinAero](https://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-lean-rs5/)

> Windows 10 Lean is a new cut down edition of Windows 10 RS5. Microsoft
>   is working on a new cut down version of Windows 10 for the "Redstone
>   5" feature update of Windows 10. It is called "Windows 10 Lean",
>   starts in Windows 10 S Mode, and currently identifies itself as
>   "Windows 10 CloudE".
>
> This new cut down Windows 10 version doesn't include many basic
>   things. It comes without wallpapers, CD/DVD drivers, and apps like
>   Registry Editor or MMC. Its image is 2 GB smaller than Windows 10 Pro.
>
> As of this writing, the user can just copy the missing apps, e.g.
>   regedit.exe, from another Windows 10 instance, and they will work
>   without issues. The OS has no software restrictions for first-party
>   apps.
>
> The new edition has started shipping with the release of Windows 10
>   Build 17650 (RS5), which was recently released to Windows Insiders. It
>   is not clear what Microsoft plans regarding this new edition of
>   Windows 10. Currently, an advantage is that it shrinks the
>   installation size by 2GB in comparison to regular Windows 10 versions.

Comment: Doesn't copying binaries from other Windows edition violate EULA?

Comment: Can you please reference your source for this information?

Comment: Run5k Here: https://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-lean-rs5/v

Comment: Please be aware that effectively plagiarizing other sites without attribution is discouraged here. If you are copying content then you should blockquote the referred text and cite the source giving proper attribution where necessary. You should read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).